# Is React reduxtoolkit persist on session storage good location to persist user data?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am building a fullstack MERN app that allows users to login and perform some actions.
Some components are to display or work with user data like email, name, status etc.
Instead of sending a http request to the backend on every component that needs userData, is it a good practice to persist the userData on @reduxtookit persist not on local storage but session storage because if the user closes the browser without logging out, the data is gone on next session, which sounds good to me as logout would do the same.

So instead of sending a http request with loader function on react router v6.4 on every component. I probably should persist the data on login and use useSelector to access the data from every component that needs to work with it.

My question is: is this a good practice?

I persisted the data on reduxtoolkit persist and the pages were a lot more split second quicker than getting the data straight from the backend.

Comment: You should save your data in the store

Comment: I did, and the persisted the data but as a newbie, I never seen anyone do that so I was wondering if it’s a good practice to persist such data like that of the user in store to reduxtoolkit persist.